# Is it possible to observe ATP energy transport in table experiment?

Tags: biochemistry, home-experiment, energy

Is it possible to take AMP or ADP, then phosphorylate it convert to ATP to charge with energy, then transport to other place an then observe energy freeing?

In table / home / school experiment?